# In Java logger how can I add check to see if they output code of a certain log level

Tags: java, logging

I'm making a program that uses a custom library I built. Both of them are using the Java util logging class and making log files. I want to have code that will set a boolean to true if a log is made with the WARNING level. Aside from scanning the log file looking for Warning comments what I can do to achieve this?

Comment: [Pointcuts](https://blog.espenberntsen.net/tag/pointcut/) rush to mind, but I have to wonder... *what* are you doing?

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful to know what library you are using, exactly.  I think you can check the logging level inputs given on the command line with `System.getProperties()`, and I think a custom `Handler` installed at the root logger level will tell you when a logging statement has actually happened.

Comment: To make a long story short, I have made a library that makes docbook files and can handle/parse certain xml input. I have another program that uses that library and feeds it the xml. There's a certain situation where the library will give a warning that says "this xml should've been structured differently we can still translate it into a docbook file but it won't have the proper formatting." However the program that's using the library is the program that needs to know if a warning was output to the log file. They're both logging onto the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to analyze the log file, I would change the library implementation to do something like this:

```
class Parser {
    private List<String> warnings = new ArrayList<>();

    public Boolean hasWarnings() {
        return warnings.size() > 0
    }

    public List<String> getWarnings() {
        return warnings;
    }

    public Object parse(String xml) {
        // parse the xml

        if (needToIssueWarning) {
            String msg = "warning!";
            warnings.add(msg);
            logger.warn(msg);
        }

        return parsedData;
    }
}
```

and at the calling site:

```
private void run() {
    Parser parser = new Parser();
    parsedData = parse(xmlString);
    if (parser.hasWarnings()) {
        warnings = parser.getWarnings();
        //do something with the warnings
    }
}
```

If you would go for a solution to parse the log, there would be no guarantee that the log level includes warnings, it might be set to error, and then you would miss the message

Answer (score 0):

Create [java.util.logging.Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/logging/Filter.html) that looks for the [WARNING](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#getLevel()) level message.
Install that filter on a [Handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html#setFilter(java.util.logging.Filter)) of the root logger.

```
public class WarningFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
        if (Level.WARNING.equals(record.getLevel())) {
           //Set your boolean.
        }
        return true; //Allow all records to pass.
    }
}
```